# Concurrent chunking not working in fineuploader

Tags: fine-uploader, chunking

I have been struggling since last 4 days to get concurrent chunking in fine uploader. But it is not working.
It is dividing the images to parts but the files are not sending to back end file.

While uploading larger files it is showing the error as below.

**Warning**:  fopen(chunks\18a9ca63-5503-48ab-a17b-59a29c65310f\0): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **D:\xampp\htdocs\fineuploaderv2\html\templates\server\handler.php** on line **138**

**Warning**:  stream_copy_to_stream() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **D:\xampp\htdocs\fineuploaderv2\html\templates\server\handler.php** on line **139**

**Warning**:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **D:\xampp\htdocs\fineuploaderv2\html\templates\server\handler.php** on line **140**

**Warning**:  unlink(chunks\18a9ca63-5503-48ab-a17b-59a29c65310f\0): No such file or directory in **D:\xampp\htdocs\fineuploaderv2\html\templates\server\handler.php** on line **147**
{"success":true,"uuid":"18a9ca63-5503-48ab-a17b-59a29c65310f","uploadName":"18a9ca63-5503-48ab-a17b-59a29c65310f\DosenmoorBirken1.jpg","template":"","category":""}

Please some one give the solution to solve this problem.

Comment: Concurrent chunking works fine as far as I can tell.  Looks like an issue in your server code or with your environment. You'll need to provide some detail.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `chunks` folder does not exist.

Go into the same folder as `D:\xampp\htdocs\fineuploaderv2\html\templates\server\handler.php` and make the `chunks` directory.

Or change the directory in your PHP source file to point to another, already created, directory.

Or create the chunks directory programmatically.

Note that this is not an issue with concurrent chunking, but an issue with your server setup.

Comment: Chunks folder is exist in the server folder. while chunking uplaoded file name sending as null why i am unable to understand.

Comment: Chunking initialization code is:                            chunking:
   {
   enabled: true,
   partSize: 1000000, 
            paramNames: {
                    partIndex: 'qqpartindex',
                    partByteOffset: 'qqpartbyteoffset',
                    chunkSize: 'qqchunksize',
                    totalFileSize: 'qqtotalfilesize',
                    totalParts: 'qqtotalparts',
                    filename: 'qqfile'
                },    
   concurrent: {
    enabled: true,
    maxConnections:3
   },success: {
    endpoint: 'server/endpoint.php'
   
    
   }
  }

Comment: I don't believe you! The errors you posted above clearly correlate with a missing chunks folder. You are also clearly getting the filename (`'DosenmoorBirken1.jpg'`)